# Code is showing 'sql_connection' not defined on server while working fine on system

Tags: python-3.x, server, mysql-connector, sqlconnection, mysql-connector-python

I am writing a code which is using 'sql-connector-python' module of the python.
Thi code is working fine on my system, but it is showing error as **sql_connection not defined** on server(AWS Instance).

Here is the code:-

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from csv import reader
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import datetime
import hashlib
import random
import base64
import requests
import logging



logging.basicConfig(filename="smpa_hit.log", format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', filemode='a')
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)



# Making SQL connection
try:
    sql_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="host",
        user="user",
        password="pwd"
    )

except Exception as e:
    logger.info("MySQL connection failed as :: {}".format(e))

crsr = sql_connection.cursor()
```

It is showing error in line "crsr = sql_connection.cursor()" that means the sql_connection was enable to establish.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Appears to be a scoping issue, could you try moving the last line above `except` and re-running?

Comment: Sorry, which line? @vmachan

Comment: I meant copy the line `crsr = sql_connection.cursor()` above the `except` inside the `try` block